# how to get value of specifc string in coldfusion with regex

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am trying to get the url value of the following string with coldfusion, i am using list function but i am lost how do i get that please advice

```
<cfsavecontent variable="foo">
      function modalwindow() {
    url = "http://www.idea.com?mycode=9&pagenum=-1&sortBy=1&sortOrder=1";
    mywin = window.open (url,"win",'toolbar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,copyhistory=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=878,height=810');
    mywin.focus();
    return false;
    }
  </cfsavecontent>  
    <cfset a = listgetat(foo,2,"url")>
      <cfoutput>#a#</cfoutput>
```

but i am getting weird results, i need to fetch the `URL` value

Comment: This might be difficult to answer without knowing what assumptions can be made about the string being parsed.  Will it always be just as pictured, but with a different URL?  If so, look for the url="URL" pattern.  Not sure where you're going with the listgetAt.  Note delimiters can only be one character so a delimiter of "url" means "u" OR "r" OR "l" can be a delimiter. Probably not what you want.

Comment: url value can be chnaged, i just wanna grab the url = "whatever it is"

Comment: the way it is pictured, yes it is always gonna be like this, only url value gets changed

Comment: Saying you get "weird results" isn't very helpful. Showing us what the weird results *are* *is* more helpful. Also telling us why you think they're weird is also helpful (although more for you, as part of working out what you're doing).

Comment: @adam: Weird means if i use list operation, i get (value or something like that

Comment: This sort of information belongs in your question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will return the URL and accounts for the whitespace being optional, however I should add the disclaimer that this is a little brittle and probably not a good way of going about whatever it is you're after for several reasons.

```
#reReplaceNoCase( foo, '.*url\s*=\s*"(.*?)".*', '\1' )#
```

Comment: can u explain this a little bit, like if something else needs to extracted, i can only change the url to something else or it will only work for url

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not really following you. If you want to extract something else, then modify the regex to match the string you are interested in. This regex will allow for any URL, but it will only find the URL argument in the code.  You asked how to get the URL and that's what I showed. If there's another specific bit you want to parse, edit the question to reflect that or ask a new one. If you want to know more about how regex works, then I suggest you read a reference on it. https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Regular+expression+syntax

Comment: sorry if i moving away from my question, but can i just like this: replace the mywin value `mywin = window.open (url,"win",'toolbar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,copyhistory=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=878,height=810');` to this: `mywin = $.fancybox('href' :url,'width': '500');`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking.  If this answer satisfies the original question above, please accept it.  If you have another question about finding/replacing text I would recommend you start a new question and expound fully on it there.

Comment: I would use the following for the capture group rather than trying to use the lazy operator with a wildcard: `([^""]*)` (the double quote being doubled b/c it's inside double quotes itself).

Comment: I considered that David, but double quotes are not valid in a URL nor would it be possible in this context assuming the JavaScript was well-formed.  I concede this makes the regex more "brittle" but I asked the OP in a comment and he stated that the rest of the string could be expected to never change, thus the assumptions.  Is there another reason (such as performance) to avoid the lazy wildcard on such a small string?

Comment: @brad: there is a Problem with the code, it always pick the address bar url rather than the function url, is there anyway we make it detect the url we are referring to

Comment: @Brad: I am making an update like this: it is not working: `<cfset new = Replace(reReplaceNoCase(foo,'function genPDF() { url=\s*=\s*"(.*?)".*', '\1'),'http://','https://','ALL')>`

Comment: You probably need to escape special characters like parenthesis.  Please read the regex reference I linked to in my answer.